# How to Add Jtable Into JCombobox

Tags: jcombobox

experts I want to add Jtable into Jcombobox gettnig results in Mysql table with tow column
and if user selected a combotable item,the  selectet item will show in Jtextfield

Answer (score 0):

```
@Thamindu,
```

Please make sure you ask the question clearly. Seems you don't care about what you write. (for eg. tow, combotable) 
Why do you need to add a jtable in to a jcombo box. It's a quite rare thing to hear someone trying to do.